# How to get Configurable Products to appear when out of stock

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, out-of-stock, magento-2.0.2

In STORES > Configuration > CATALOG > inventory I have "Display Out of Stock Products" set to "Yes.

I can get Simple Products that are out of stock to appear but I cannot get a configured item that has a quantity of 0 to appear on the product attribute drop down list on the public side of the site.

How can I get configured products that are out of stock to appear?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem so I created a module to fix it. It's available from here: https://github.com/pkarsai/show-out-of-stock-products-magento2

Tested with Magento 2.2.7.

See this my answer to a similar question for more info: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/268626/63748